# Cannot access files in virtual directory in iis with non English character

Tags: iis, server

I have a file in the virtual directory with a filename containing non-English characters **ö**. When we try to access the path with is not acceptable.

Is there any settings on the server or iis to resolve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1. Open the iis, double click the 'Request Filtering' icon
2. in the 'File Name Extension' right click->Edit Feature Settings...' the file 'web.config'
3. check the option 'Allow double escaping' (this option is unchecked by defualt)
4. repeat all above 3 steps for the 'defualt website' (or whatever you have given the name to your site)
5. re-start the IIS

Comment: Making the changes sill facing same issue.

Comment: How did you access the files in virtual directory? url or what?